# How to write a "scope" on a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have these models: a `Physician` has many `Patients` through their `Appointments`.

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end
 
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end
 
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

I want to write a scope or something similar so that I can find all Patients of a given Physician whose Appointments are confirmed.

What is the most idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this with a has_many :through association:

```
has_many :confirmed_patients, :through => :appointments, :source => :patient, :class_name => 'Patient', :conditions => { :confirmed => true }
```